# My Netbaeans IDE Dont Show Library Folder

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm newbie at Java netbeans , I am trying to load mysql driver, but my Netbeans IDE don't show libary folder in my Project.

```
try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            System.out.println("Its My First Project");

          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mychakki", "root", "password");
            System.out.println("Connection Established ");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :" +e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Please add a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Is that a Maven, Gradle or Ant (="native") project?